# Changing URLs with multiple ids from Django 1 to Django 2

Tags: python, url, django-2.0

In Django 1x I can do URLs with two ids in the URL like this:

url.py

```
('^profile/(?P<cpk>[0-9]+)/env/(?P<envid>[0-9]+)/$', views.EnvironmentDetailView.as_view(), name='environment'),
```

HTML template

```
"{% url 'myapp:environment' cpk=environment.client.id envid=environment.id %}"
```

models.py

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('myapp:envmanager', args =[self.client.pk])
```

views.py

```
class EnvironmentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    '''Detail view of environment'''
    model = Environment
    pk_url_kwarg ="envid"
    template_name = 'myapp/environment.html'
```

But when I upgraded to Django 2.0 I tried:

urls.py

```
path('profile/<int:client_id>/env/<int:pk>/', views.EnvironmentDetailView.as_view(), name='environment'),
```

html templates

```
"{% url 'myapp:environment' client_id=environment.client.id pk=environment.id %}"
```

views.py

```
class EnvironmentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    '''Detail view of environment'''
    model = Environment
    pk_url_kwarg ="environment_id"
    template_name = 'myapp/environment.html'
```

and got this error

```
AttributeError: Generic detail view EnvironmentDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

How do you properly reference URL links with two id?

Comment: What do you need `cpk` for? It seems you do not use it.

Comment: maybe: `pk_url_kwarg ="environment_id"` => `pk_url_kwarg ="pk"`

Comment: @PawełKordowski cpk was a variable used to keep django from confusing the two id keys

Comment: @PawełKordowski ok I guess that worked. Post it as an answer